# Loop through divs with given class and name

Tags: jquery

I have multiple divs in my page as:

```
<div imageId='image5' name='5' class='speechBubble'>
<div imageId='image5' name='5' class='speechBubble'>
<div imageId='image6' name='6' class='speechBubble'>
...
```

With jquery, I want to loop these divs for the given userId. I need to say loop divs that have class 'speechBubble' and name n (5,6)

Thank you

Comment: Thought about using xpath? Works for everything but IE (as per usual).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use the [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) and [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) functions:

```
$('.speechBubble').filter(function() {
    return this.name.match(/^[56]{1}$/);
}).each(function(index, element) {
    // TODO: do something with the element
    // for example get the imageId attribute
    var imageId = $(element).attr('imageId');
});
```

If you want to match against a userId variable you don't need the filter function. You could do this:

```
$('.speechBubble[name=' + userId + ']').each(function(index, element) {
    // TODO: do something with the element
    // for example get the imageId attribute
    var imageId = $(element).attr('imageId');
});
```

Comment: Not working for me? This is in another .each function and I'm alerting in it so I'm sure there is a problem
$('.speechBubble').filter(function() {
                    return this.name.match(userId);
                }).each(function(index, element) {
                    alert("..");
                });

Comment: @Pabuc, what is your `userId` variable? It should be a regular expression. Look at my answer more carefully. If `userId` is simply a number you could do this more easily without using the .filter function: `$('.speechBubble[name=' + userId + ']').each(...`

Comment: Can you please change [56] with a variable? like userıd.. I'll not be using fix numbers. Tried return this.name.match(userId); but didn't work.

Comment: I need to do it with a variable since it can be anything. Not 5 or 6. I'm getting userId from the outer .each() function.

Answer (score 1):

**Easy Way**

```
$(".speechBubble").each(function(){
    if($(this).attr("id")>=userId){ // assumin userId and id of .speechBubble as int vals
        // take userId from where u have to loop
    }
})
```

**Thats what you wanted ?**

Comment: Yes but I need to do it without looping all speechbubbles. There may be 100 of them and don't want to loop in them. Just need to loop in speechBubbles with the desired id.